# Ember: Locking a form on page load without hard-coding "disabled"

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have several forms with several inputs. My boss has asked me to find a way to disable the forms and have a lock/unlock button. So the user will go to the form, click unlock to make changes, then lock and/or save the form. The main problem is trying to find out how to do this without hardcoding "disabled=true" into all of the inputs (probably several hundred).

I'm 90% of the way. I have the toggleLock action working, and I even have it so the form will lock even when you transition within the same route to a different model. The problem is that the form doesn't lock the first time the page is loaded or if the page is refreshed.

Here's the code:
Available at: https://github.com/djbreen7/ember-sandbox

**app/templates/meals/view.hbs**

```
<form class="edit-form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Meal Name</label>
    {{input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="" value=model.name}}
  </div>
  ...
  <button id="toggle-lock" type="button" class="btn btn-default" {{action 'toggleLock'}}>Unlock</button>
</form>
```

**app/routes/meals/view.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  beforeModel(controller) {
    if (!this.get('isLocked')) {
      controller.send('toggleLock');
    }
  },

  model(params, controller) {
    if (!this.get('isLocked')) {
      console.log('attempting to lock due to transition');
      controller.send('toggleLock');
    }
    return this.modelFor('meals').findBy('id', parseInt(params.meal_id));
  },

  isLocked: false,

  lockForm: function() {
    if (this.get('isLocked')) {
      Ember.$('.edit-form').find('input').prop('disabled', true);
      Ember.$('#toggle-lock').text('Unlock');
    } else {
      Ember.$('.edit-form').find('input').prop('disabled', false);
      Ember.$('#toggle-lock').text('Lock');
    }
  }.observes('isLocked'),

  actions: {
    toggleLock: function() {
      if (this.get('isLocked')) {
        console.log('unlocking');
        this.set('isLocked', false);
      } else {
        console.log('locking');
        this.set('isLocked', true);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Blockquote

You can solve this an easier way, these are the steps you can follow:

1. If you want that your form starts locked you must set  `isLocked:true`
2. Remove  `lockForm` function
3. Add to your inputs the `disable` property. This will enable or disable your inputs depending on `isLocked.
4. `{{input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="" value=model.name disabled=isLocked}}`
5. Remove  `controller.send('toggleLock');` from `model` and `beforeModel` functions, is unnecesary because you setted `isLocked` to true
6. Add the `resetController` hook to handle transitions within the same route

   ```
   resetController: function(controller){
     controller.set('isLocked', true);
   }
   ```

Here's a running example https://ember-twiddle.com/fd75547e27faf867ce0daeb9eb65db14?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C

Comment: Thanks. I'm afraid this may be the solution. I'm trying to find a way to do it without going through hundreds of lines of code to add `disabled=isLocked`, but I believe it is likely going to be the only way. I'll stick around to see if any more answers show up. This is a very good explanation though. If I had the rep to upvote I would.

Comment: I was able to get this to work without having to go in and adjust all of the forms. I wish I could share more, but my boss had written a component. So basically the `disabled` attribute exists in the component. Any form that we want to disable we wrap in the component. Then, following your suggestion works perfectly and only having to have the `disabled=isLocked` within the component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the power of jQuery. With jQuery, you can disable all the input fields in a page (or part of a page) in one line:

```
$("input").prop("disabled", true);
```

If you have textareas, you have to put one line for them too:

```
$("textarea").prop("disabled", true);
```

**What if there are some fields those will be disabled everytime:**

If you have some input's those are already disabled, you should store their original values as an attribute (just before setting every input's state to disabled):

```
$('input:disabled').attr('prev_disabled',true);
```

So that you can restore them after toggling twice (just after setting every input's state to enabled):

```
$('input[prev_disabled]').prop('disabled',true);
```

**How is it possible to use jQuery with Ember.js:**

You can use it in your actions, component life-cycles, Ember run loops etc. (There are tons of examples on web, such as [this blog](http://www.programwitherik.com/how-to-initialize-a-jquery-component-with-ember-js/))

Example usage in actions:

```
actions: {
    lockRequested: function() {
        this.$('input:disabled').attr('prev_disabled',true);
        this.$("input").prop("disabled", true);
    },
    unlockRequested: function() {
        this.$("input").prop("disabled", false);
        this.$('input[prev_disabled]').prop('disabled',true);
    }
}
```

If you want to lock the inputs just after entering the page, use component lifecycles (e.g. `didRender`, `didInsertElement` or ember run loop)